# Are the bones that make up Wolverine's inner ear Adamantium?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

Since the inner workings of the ear are made of bones, does that mean that his inner ear is also coated in Adamantium?

Comment: All of his bones are adamantium. That includes all of his bones. If you're wondering if a particular bone is adamantium, ask yourself if it's a bone. If the answer is "yes" then it's covered in adamantium.

Comment: **covered by** adamantium... not made from.

Comment: I guess if it were vibranium, he'd be deaf...

Comment: @Valorum Given how the adamantium was ‘IV’ed’ into his body, wouldn't it make sense if any bones that are not connected to other bones were not covered? How would the adamantium have travelled through pure skin or muscle tissue without any trace to reach such a bone?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - http://i.stack.imgur.com/lgqse.png

Comment: @Valorum That's not an answer.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I'm no doctor, but bones aren't connected to each other *with bone*. They're connected by stuff that isn't bone such as muscle, adipose tissue, cartilage, etc.

Comment: @Valorum I'm no doctor, but I'm pretty sure the knee bones connected to the thigh bone, and the thigh bones connected to the hip bone. It says nothing about cartilage or muscle.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - Are you sure you're not a doctor? Them's some fine doctorin' words you're speaking.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr [Obligatory reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVHqTzyZ-oM) to some particularly surreal scenes of the most surreal episode of an exceptionally surreal spy-fi TV series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Probably not.

Wolverines Adamantium skeleton is an offesnive/defensive feature that makes his attacks stronger and protects his external frame making him stronger.

Wolverine has been shown to have had Adamantium bonded to him by at least two different methods - plating bolted directly to the bone or direct injection into the bone marrow using [Adamantium Beta](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Adamantium#Adamantium_Beta).

#### Adamanitum plating

We can rule out plating of the ear bones as they are tiny and plating offers no real benefit. Plus, due to their tiny size they would heal quickly.

#### Bone Marrow injection

We can probably rule this out scientifically. In some Marvel comics, Wolverine has been shown to have had the Adamantium injected directly into his bone marrow. But, by age two the ear bones lose their marrow cavities and are completely ossified. Since Wolverines powers only kicked in during his fathers death well after infancy, and the adamantium injections happened decades later we can rule out his ear bones being adamantium bonded.

> Initially, the malleus and incus form as a single structure, and it is only later that they separate to form two separate bones. Ossification continues through the entire fetal period, and the newly formed bones also have a transient bone marrow cavity. The marrow cavity is still present at birth, in both the malleus and the incus, and with continued ossification is lost during the first two years after birth. Postnatally, first the malleus and then the incus lose their marrow spaces. [UNSW Embryology Article](https://embryology.med.unsw.edu.au/embryology/index.php/Hearing_-_Middle_Ear_Development)

Comment: If his teeth aren't adamantium, it's highly unlikely that his inner ear bones are.

Comment: The part on bone marrow makes sense, but you seem to have discarded the plating out of hand with little justification.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Teeth aren't bones.