# Can X-23 physically grow?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, logan

Laura, also known as X-23 is a young mutant who can heal.

> Additionally, X-23 is a clone of Logan.

If her bones are covered in adamantium, how can she ever grow?

Comment: Should this be tagged with [logan] for the new movie? Or perhaps [marvel-comics] if you were interested in just those.

Comment: Like Wolverine, her bones aren’t covered in adamantium.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

X-23 actually only has adamantium plated claws sheathed in her forearm and in her feet. She escaped the facility where she was being held at before they could do a full coating of adamantium through her skeletal structure like Wolverine. Please see one shot comic *[X-23: Target X](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/x-23-target-x/4050-18171/)*.

Comment: That is really interesting! Thanks for the comic reference, I will be checking that out!

Comment: This raises a question in my mind- did Logan's claws grow as he grew (and will X23's)? When did Logan first discover his claws?

Comment: Not sure about the comics, but in the movies he knew when he was young. I think 5 or 8 years old.

Comment: @MichaelMine: "It made his teenage years very awkward..."

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Thanks for adding the link! There was a Wolverine issue right after Magneto pulled the Adamantium right out of Wolverine when he discovered he had his bone claws. I don't quite remember which one it was though.

Comment: @kelzak this meaning Wolverine thought his claws were made for him out of adamantium?

Comment: @Michael Miner The way it was presented before the reveal in Woverine #75 (found it!), everyone thought that the Weapon X program gave him his claws along with his Adamantium skeleton.

Comment: At what point does Logan's skeleton become adamantium/adamantium-infused in the cinematic universe?

Comment: @TylerH They show it in Wolverine Origins.

Comment: More importantly, are they're inner ear bones adamantium plated? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/132554/40833

Answer (score 22):

Your question is difficult to answer in one word, because there are several factors at play here, but, the short answer is **yes**.

First, **X-23, as she is portrayed in the comics, does NOT have an adamantium skeleton**.  Only her claws were coated.  So, obviously, this should not impede her growth in a significant way.  It's possible that a movie version of her might not have this same origin and instead have a full adamantium skeleton, however, this would be an unwise move for a simple reason... actual kids grow up.  If your child actor can't grow because you've decided her entire skeleton is fused with adamantium, then you've got a problem for any sequels.

Secondly, **we must consider what counts as growing up**.  Plenty of people have some sort of condition that limits their physical skeletal development, but we still say they "grew up", because the rest of their body usually does reach some level of maturity.  So, *if* X-23's skeleton became coated with adamantium, chances are that yes, under most definitions of the term, she would grow-up.

**The only remaining things we need to consider are her healing factor stunting her aging process in general, regardless of adamantium, and whether, hypothetically, it would stunt her physical development if she did have an adamantium skeleton**.  The answer to the first question is **probably no**, she seems to be aging at a normal rate up until adulthood, as Logan did.  Once she does reach physical maturity, it's likely she will remain young for a long time, just as Logan did.  But, yes, **adamantium is the strongest substance known to man and it is likely that her skeletal structure, *if* it were infused with adamantium at a young age, would remain small and unable to grow more.**  However, she would still almost certainly experience other symptoms of maturity (although, adamantium is mildly toxic in canon in large amounts, and it's *possible* that at such a young age, even with her healing factor, a whole skeletal covering might raise the level of toxic metals in her body to a point where it interferes hormonally as well).

Answer (score -1):

Actually,  her healing factor won't stop her from growing up.  It will just slow her aging waaay down.  Wolverine himself took many generations to grow up.  Professor Xavier  even remarked there's no way to determine Logan's real age.