# Are only the bones in Wolverine's skeleton adamantium?

Tags: marvel, comics, wolverine

I was discussing this with a colleague at work, and we couldn't find any definitive answers.

Are, for example, the joints in Wolverine still regular ones, or are they covered in adamantium as well? And what about his cartilage?

In short, what are the ears of Wolverine made of?

Comment: Well it's X-Cartilage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are the bones that make up Wolverine's inner ear Adamantium?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132554/are-the-bones-that-make-up-wolverines-inner-ear-adamantium)

Comment: @CBredlow related but not a dupe IMO, this question asks for stuff​ that _isn't_ bone (joint, cartilage, etc). The suggested dupe asks about some actual bones, and the answer addresses said bones, without considering the cartilage of the outer ear (or nose).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Punisher blows Wolverine's face off in *Punisher* #16 (2002). While the ears are unharmed, the nose was blown off as well, so no adamantium there. Probably not in the ears as well.

[image: adamantium face on Wolverine's body]

For the record, adamantium cartilage *does* exist (partially), but I don't know of it being present in Wolverine; in fact, I'm pretty sure it's the contrary. From an archive of Marvel's website entry on [Deathlok (Michael Collins)](https://web.archive.org/web/20180622010001/https://marvel.com/universe/Deathlok_(Michael_Collins)):

> The rest of the body is made up of synthetic parts. His skeleton is composed of unbreakable Adamantium, while his muscles and cartilage are a flexible steel/Adamantium alloy.

Note that Deathlok's adamantium body isn't a mutation, but then again neither is Wolverine's; both are artificial, so it appears the presence of adamantium cartilage relies on the process of providing/molding the adamantium.

Comment: Pretty articulate for someone with no lips, cheeks or tongue...

Comment: Now I'm wondering if his eyes are adamantium, or they're just prioritized higher for regeneration.